# Angular ng-repeat on an Array of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I need to display something x times in the row, but there is no `do(x times)` in Angular, nor I would like to use additional functions in my controller.

Knowing that

```
?Array.from({length:5})
(5) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Is it possible make the following code work without adding additional functions or filters in the controller (without using a controller at all).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app>
  [1,2] - OK:
  <div ng-repeat="x in [1,2]">
    > {{x}}
  </div>

  Array.from({length:5}) - NOK:
  <div ng-repeat="x in Array.from({length:5})">
    > {{x}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**PS**

*I don't want to display numbers, I just need to display 5 `>`*

**PPS.**

Practical need:
I need to display the last page of a paginated table, have "availableRowsNumber" and "itemsPerPage", so I need to complete with empty rows, to display the "standard height":

```
<div ng-repeat="x in Array.from({length:itemsPerPage-itemsPerPage%availableRowsNumber})">
    <tr></tr>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if="$index < 5"

Comment: Why wouldn't you like to add functions in your controller? And if you only need to display 5, why do you need an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @MikeFeltman I don't have an initial array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.constructor`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(5) track by $index">
     <span>something that you want to display</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: good solution! remark that without `track by` does not work! ...do you have an explanation why `Array.from({length:5})` doesn't work?

Comment: The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object. So basically you need something to base it on.

Comment: I don't think I understand your last comment... as I mention in OP, I have a `[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]` array via `Array.from({length:5})`... it should iterate on it, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe angular might not be able to render it from the view. I am not sure about the Array keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-if like Mike had mentioned:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-if="$index < 5">
</div>
```

You could also use limitTo:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 5 track by $index">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what OP asks. The question is how to do an `ng-repeat` n times, without having a predefined array and touching a controller or filter